# Can I separate this dishwasher motor from the sump?

Tags: dishwasher, pump

I have an LG LDP7808SS dishwasher that is just over a year old (out of warranty of course) and the circulation pump is making loud noises. Can I separate the motor from the sump and just replace the motor? That is the cheaper option at around $100 versus $200 for the motor and sump assembly. I tried pulling the motor out of the sump but it won't budge. The sump itself looks as though it can be opened, but I can't figure out how and don't want to break it.  Any advice?

[This is what the assembly looks like](https://partsdr.com/part/abt72989205-pump-and-case-assembly?gclid=Cj0KCQjw94WZBhDtARIsAKxWG-8P5OyatvVw7zRDyyYEEAFuNWdDpwxs189eLGLoMauM7KjOefzc-ogaAsk8EALw_wcB)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: we do not know your DIY skills, how would you rate them

Comment: Include pictures of just the motor and just the pump.

Comment: From a billion miles looks like you take the face screws out which joins plastic to plastic, then twist the top clockwise. Can see some areas around the outside that have clearly twisted in to place

Comment: how do you know that the motor is noisy?

Comment: After several failed attempts to separate the two I gave in and bought the whole assembly.  It's installed now and the noise is gone.  I'll get a little more abusive with the old assembly to see if I can get them apart.  Assuming I'll probably be replacing this more than once (they don't build em like they used to!).  Thanks all for your input.

Comment: Split the difference use a rebuilt unit. You may also get credit for the bad one.

Answer (score 1):

From a picture on the internet, the answer is "definitely maybe". It is very hard to tell from just that pic. It may be intentional to get people to buy the whole unit, or it may not be intended to be separately serviceable.

Since the motor and sump *are* (apparently) available as separate replacement parts, though, it seems that the answer is "yes" you can separate them - it wouldn't make sense to sell individual parts that can only be replaced as a unified whole. The how, though, cannot be determined by looking at the picture.

Since you're planning on replacing yours, remove it from the dishwasher and see if you can separate it. If you can, then bravo! You can order just the pump, replace it, and put the extra cash into a celebratory beverage.

If you can't and/or you break it in the process, well, you gave it the ol' college try and now you have to replace the combo.